# Is it always true that $Mat(id, F, E)=Mat(id, E,F)^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Is it always true for change of basis matrices from and to any bases $E,F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that

$$Mat(id, F, E)=Mat(id,E,F)^{-1}$$?

---

$Mat(id,F,E)$ is a change of basis matrix from basis $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Can you define what "Math(L,F,E)" means

Answer (score 0):

The way you phrase the problem is incorrect. When proving such equalities regarding matrices, you must have an **ordered** basis. Otherwise, the equalities would obviously be false.

So let's fix two ordered bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for any finite dimensional vector space $V$. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. I shall use the following notation:

$[T]_\alpha ^\beta$ to mean the matrix representation of $T$ in the ordered bases of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then the change of coordinate matrix can be represented by $[I]_\alpha ^\beta$

> **Proposition**: For a linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ with ordered bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $T$ is invertible if and only if $[T]_\alpha ^ \beta$ is invertible. Moreover, $[T^{-1}]_\beta ^ \alpha = ([T]_\alpha ^ \beta ) ^{-1}$

This is easily verified. For example, if $T$ is invertible linear operator, then there exists $T^{-1}$. Then

$$I = [I]_\alpha^\alpha= [T^{-1} T]_\alpha ^ \alpha = [T^{-1}]_\beta ^\alpha [T]_\alpha ^ \beta$$

Specializing to $T = I$, which is clearly invertible, then you have that the inverse to $[I]_\alpha ^ \beta$ is given by $[I^{-1}]_\beta ^ \alpha = [I]_\beta ^ \alpha$.